# Allow CP sorting on an added EntryTableAttribute

Tags: plugin-development, entries, control-panel

I am adding a column to the entry table with links to reverse related entries:

```
    public function defineAdditionalEntryTableAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'blockParent' => Craft::t('Parent'),
        );
    }

public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    switch ($attribute)
    {
        case 'blockParent':
        {
            $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry, [
                'relatedTo' => [
                    'targetElement' => $entry,
                    'field' => 'contentSections.blocks',
                ]
            ]);

            $html = '';

            foreach ($criteria as $entry) {
                $html .= craft()->templates->render('_elements/element', array(
                    'element' => $entry,
                ));
            }

            return $html;
        }

    }
}
```

Works great. Only I want to make the column sortable (based on the title of the first entry of each).

Is there a way to sort on these types of added columns? `modifyEntrySortableAttributes` seems to only work on real attributes, not added ones.